# When do hal properties get updated

Tags: dbus, hal

I'm calling GetProperty on a org.freedesktop.Hal.Device from my handler during a PropertyNotified signal.  I'm only calling GetProperty on properties that have been added or changed.

When I call GetProperty during property adds, I'm getting a org.freedesktop.Hal.NoSuchProperty exception.  I'm also worried that during changes, I'm getting the old values.

When should I be calling GetProperty?  What race conditions are involved?

Answer (score 1):

How about *DeviceExists* method (like [here](http://www.linux.org.ru/view-message.jsp?msgid=3052695)):

```
    if device.PropertyExists('info.product'):
        return device.GetProperty('info.product')
    return "unknown"
```

And *PropertyModified* signal, ([ex from real world](http://www.nabble.com/-PATCH--HAL-support-for-SyncEngine-%2B-misc-fixes-(works-on-FreeBSD!)-td16224699.html)):

```
 #
 # _CBHalDeviceConnected
 #
 # INTERNAL
 #
 # Callback triggered when a device is connected through Hal.
 #

 def _CBHalDeviceConnected(self, obj_path): 
...
 self.device.connect_to_signal("PropertyModified", 
   self._CBHalDeviceAuthStateChanged) 
...

#
# _CBHalDeviceAuthStateChanged
#
# INTERNAL
#
# Callback triggered when a Hal device property is changed, 
# for checking authorization state changes
#

def _CBHalDeviceAuthStateChanged(self,num_changes,properties):
 for property in properties:
 property_name, added, removed = property
 if property_name == "pda.pocketpc.password":
 self.logger.info("_CBHalDeviceAuthStateChanged: 
     device authorization state changed: reauthorizing")
 self._ProcessAuth()
```

[HAL 0.5.10 Specification](http://people.freedesktop.org/~david/hal-spec/hal-spec.html)
[D-Bus Specification](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html)
[D-Bus Tutorial](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html)